# Subversion deployment onto Windows environment

Tags: windows, svn, iis

I need to deploy an source control enviroment. I have heard Visual Source Safe is rubbish and to avoid it.

So I have been looking into SVN, but what I don't understand is how to deploy this?

We have one development server which holds all of our content, I need it so the 10+ developers can sign out files/folders work on them and return them.

The location in use is an network share hosted on the web server. So if there a 'server' installation for Windows so I can configure the repositories?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Al

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.visualsvn.com/server/ which is a free SVN server for Windows. It's very easy to setup and configure.

Comment: Thanks Nick, found that just after posting. Just need to test it and see if it does what it says on the tin :)